# parse-server logging issue How to see the logs

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is there any way in which we can see the log messages on parse-server as we were seeing on parse.com . On parse.com i used to use `console.log()` and `console.error()` . `Is there any built in setting that needs to be changed or do we have to use some external package.`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see all your console.log() and console.error() on console where you launched your parse-server.

I launch like following

> parse-server --appId YOUR_APP_ID --masterKey YOUR_MASTER_KEY --restAPIKey YOUR_REST_API_KEY --serverURL http://localhost:1337/parse --databaseURI mongodb://localhost:27017/YOUR_DATABASE --cloud main.js

and see all my console.log() there